# Is there a way to avoid this SQL join?

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding whether the join can be removed. There are multiple id's that need to be found and the latest record / row for each of these id's. So for example there could be 5 dates for each row and we only want the latest dated record. So sending in a series of id's will return only the latest row for one of those id's.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   (SELECT id,
               max(date) AS latest_date
        FROM   table_name
        WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
        GROUP  BY id) AS latest_records
       JOIN table_name t
         ON t.id = latest_records.id
            AND t.date = latest_records.latest_date
```

The columns look like for example:

```
id, date, column
1, 24-2-2, data
1, 24-2-1, data1
2, 24-2-2, data
2, 24-2-1, data1
```

And the query should return only say

```
id, date, column
1, 24-2-2, data
2, 24-2-2, data
```

Comment: Yes, but it can be done in different ways. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, _row_ not record is the correct terminology here.

Comment: What's the expected result if an id has the same, most recent date, twice?

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports window functions, you can use the `RANK()` window function to assign a rank to each row based on the specified ordering, then filter and retrieve rows where the rank is equal to 1 (Multiple rows with identical most recent date will be selected) :

```
select id, dt, col
from (
  select *, rank() over(partition by id order by dt desc) as rnk 
  from table_name 
  where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
) as s
where rnk = 1;
```

If there are multiple records with the most recent date for a given ID, and you need to select only one of those records, consider using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`.

[Demo on mysql 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikW7iuYw)

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a simple query as below,

```
select id, max(date) as latest_date from table_name 
where id in (1,2,3,4) group by id
```

Or you can also go by `row_number()` if you have multiple values,

```
select id, date as latest_date from
(select id, date, row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as rnk from table_name 
where id in (1,2,3,4)) where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Note that OP wants to select all columns.